# How to get emmet to work with flexbox syntax

Tags: sublimetext3, flexbox

I am new to flexbox, I use Sublime and the Emmet plugin, which almost types 75% of the CSS syntax for me. Now the problem is that Emmet doesn't quite support flexbox, and it's a pain to type the syntax, especially given that I am new to flexbox.

Now how do I go about making Emmet give me the flexbox syntax in Sublime?

Comment: Just to double-check: You're looking for help with CSS flex properties, not the Apache Flex framework?  Your question looks like it needs retagging as "flexbox", but I wanted to confirm before editing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a snippet at plugin in "Package Control" "CSS Flexbox snippets".
Works for CSS/LESS/Sass/SCSS & Stylus.